# Monitoring traffic of phone through charles proxy?

Tags: certificate, proxy

I am using Charles proxy to monitor https traffic for which we have to import a certificate in the phone. Is there any way that my phone (Motorola Moto E2 with CyanogenMod 12.1) treats the certificate generated by charles proxy as root certificate?

Comment: Are you asking if your phone is currently treating the cert as a root cert or are you asking how to configure your phone to treat it as a root cert?

Comment: Right now its not treating it as a ROOT certificate and yes how to treat it as a root certificate?

Answer (score 0):

Download the crt file to your phone. Then go to `Settings->Security->Install from storage` and select the cert.

Comment: yes I did that but the certificate installed as a user certificate  not as a root certificate.

Comment: Why is that not sufficient? I think the root certs are stored in read-only parts of the filesystem so, without root, you can't do it.

Comment: Its not sufficient because the phone thinks that the traffic can be intercepted so it tells me to always put a lock code on it.If anyhow we can make it a root certificate it no longer tells me because it would be trusting the root certificate.

Comment: I don't think that's doable. Can you unaccept my answer to see if others can help? I'm not sure that's possible but it may be the way to go. You should edit your question and add what you did and the problems that you're having.